# Subscriber Key Considerations when Connecting with SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, bestpractice, marketing-cloud-connect

My organization is currently in the beginning stages of connecting our SFDC org with Marketing Cloud. One of the discussions has been around doing a rekey of our subscribers within Marketing Cloud. I understand it will take a service engagement with Salesforce, but I want to make sure we do it correctly.

Specifically, if we have customer information SFDC, is it generally considered a best practice to have the Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud be the Contact ID from the SFDC org, or does it matter? We want to make sure that when we connect the two clouds, we are able to have a fairly seamless back and forth communication. There were thoughts around using an internally-generated GUID in SFMC, but if this makes things more difficult in the long run, I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact ID/Lead ID is needed to be the Subscriber Keys for the Tracking information to be able to flow back to SFDC from Marketing Cloud. 
It is a requirement from Salesforce.

Comment: do you know if subscriber/contact level activities are stored somewhere  in SFDC (separated object, field for contact)? I can't find that information anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean email activity/ tracking data ?

Comment: yes, but I mean on contact level - full history of sent,opened,clicked for a selected contact in SFDC

Comment: Yes, there are ways to get that using data extracts / queries / reports

Comment: Thanks Maneesh, are you familiar with any documentation of this requirement? I'm unable to find the official Salesforce explanation.

Comment: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/       https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/

Comment: If you follow the various requirements for the MC Connect and leverage the right solutions, all the emails sent will show up in the related list "Individual Email Results", alternatively you can access it in Marketing Cloud under Contact Builder ==> All Contacts. Or, as Maneesh says, you can export the data. Depends on your requirement.